# Missing number in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I encountered a problem when I started searching for an element from an array by sorting:

```js
function missingnumber(numbers) {
  var missing = -1;
  var sorted = numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    a - b
  })
  
  for (var i = sorted[0]; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    if (numbers(i) === -1) {
      missing = i
    }
  }
  return missing;
}

var numbers = [2,4,10,7,6,11,8,9,12]//5 without sorting
var numbers = [11,19,18,17,15]//i am getting -1 with sorting

console.log(missing - number(numbers))
```

I'm trying to get the the missing number by sorting and it gives me missing number -1. Where is hole in my logic?

Comment: `number` and `numbers` .. are not functions ... yet you call `number` in the console.log and call `numbers(i)` in the loop - you claim you're getting some output as -1, but in fact, your code is invalid

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous syntax and logic errors in your code; here are a few:

- `if (numbers(i) === -1) {` has a syntax error (you probably mean `numbers[i]` as an array index) and a logic error (comparing an array index against `-1` won't tell you whether it's the missing number or not, unless the missing number happens to be `-1`).
- `console.log(missing - number(numbers))` is where you're (rightfully, at least somewhere in the code) trying to calculate the missing number by subtraction. Unfortunately, this isn't syntactically or logically correct.
- `var i = sorted[0]` should be simply `var i = 0` rather than the value of the element at index `0` in `sorted`.

Here's a working version; if there are multiple missing numbers, it returns the first one, and it's assumed that the step size is always `1` in the sequence:

```js
const missing = nums => {
  nums.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  
  for (var i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] - nums[i-1] !== 1) {
      return nums[i-1] + 1;
    }
  }
  
  return -1;
};

console.log(missing([2,4,10,7,6,11,8,9,12]));
console.log(missing([11,19,18,17,15]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Codility missing number in array solution 100% performance

```
func missingNumber( array: [Int]) -> Int {

    let length = array.count+1
    let totalSum = length * (length+1)/2

    let actualSum = array.reduce(0, { x, y in
        x + y
    })

    return totalSum - actualSum
}
```

Another solutions is

```
public func solution(_ array : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    // write your code in Swift 4.2.1 (Linux)
     var dict: [Int:  Int] = [:]

    array.map{

        dict[$0] = $0
    }

    var missingNumber = 1

    for (_, _) in dict {

        if dict[missingNumber] == nil {

            return missingNumber
        }
        missingNumber = missingNumber+1
    }

    return missingNumber
}
```